# How to avoid the "[object Object]1" when trying to find.count

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When calling this function (right now my order table is empty) I exspect the number 1

```
let id = 0;
id = await orderNumber();
```

But the id I get in return is "[object Object]1"

```
//
// Get MAX order number
//
orderNumber = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve (orderModel.find().count()+1)
    })
}
```

Anyone have an idea how to avoid that?
My purpose here is just to find the MAX number of records in orderModel (order table) and add 1 to that number.

Comment: `orderModel.find().count()` probably returns a Promise which you need to `await` to get the actual count.

Comment: I do that already :)   id = await orderNumber();

Comment: Yeah but you need to `await orderModel.find().count()`

Comment: Yes you were correct!     let id = await orderModel.find().count()+1;
   return resolve ( id );

Comment: Please post solution so I can give you credit :)

Comment: (node:14220) DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use Collection.countDocuments or Collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead

Comment: Ohh...   better switch to that one then

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll do that.

Comment: Ah yes, `countDocuments` is probably better, but the same applies there as well (needing to await the returned promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderModel.find().count()` probably returns a Promise, so you need to `await` for it to get the actual count:

*Note: as mentioned by torbenrudgaard, you're better off using `.countDocuments()`*

```
orderNumber = async () => {
    const count = await orderModel.find().count()
    return count + 1
}
```

or:

```
orderNumber = () => {
    return orderModel.find().count().then(count => count + 1)
}
```

Comment: change .find().count() with .countDocuments()  (the other one will depriciate)

Comment: I added a note :)

Answer (score 1):

```
id = await orderNumber();
orderNumber = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    orderModel.count({}, function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            res.json("Number of documents in the collection: " + result);
                            return resolve({
                                count: result
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
```